# How to make a graph over what hours of the day an event occurs (several days) and to what magnitude?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to make a chart that displays at what times of the day a specific event occurs and to what magnitude. This event is supposed to be reoccurring over several days and I want to show each day represented with its own line/colour.

Example: Let's say I want to make a graph that shows at what times and how much it rains over a specific place. I have the data of how much mm each hour delivered. Now I want all of the hours of the day (00:00-23:00) on the X-axis and the amount of rain on the Y axis. The data should be illustrated with rain event having a line during the duration of the downfall, but every day having the same legend. This means that some days it rains from 08:00-12:00 with different volumes every hour, and then again from 17:00-18:00 and another day only between 11:00-13:00. I want the two first to be part of the same legend but have a gap between them.

Sample of rain/date data:

[image: Sample of rain/date data]

Sample data without time/date formatting:

[image: Sample data without time/date formatting]

Sample picture of how it might look like, not values from the code:

[image: Sample picture of how it might look like, not values from the code]

Comment: Please post some sample data. Mock up a chart with the drawing tools or on paper and take a photo. Then edit your question and add that information. This will be possible in Excel, but it will require some careful data layout and a few charting tricks. If you can draw what you would like the chart to look like, we can work towards that. Again, edit your question to make the changes, then post a comment to alert people who follow the question.

Comment: Post updated with additional info. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one column for the hours of the day.

Then use a different column for each date and enter the mm values for the time of day.

Create an XY Scatter chart and add each column as a series, using the X values with the hours and the Y values with the mm values.

Here is an example.

[image]

If you want to plot your data as different series, the easiest way is to separate the data into different columns. You may want to use formulas to do that, or maybe even a pivot table. However you arrive at it, the data layout for the chart source is the crucial element in this approach. If you have all your data in just two columns, then you won't easily be able to produce a chart with distinct colours for each day.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. It was a life saver and I finally got it to work. I spent so many hours I tried without figuring it out, and the solution was so easy :) (could unfortunately upvote since my reputation is too low, sorry about that..)